# iterate the List and set the value with data available in another list

Tags: java, collections

I have the below two List objects, i want to iterate the addrMappingList and set the Person to the field by getting the person object from personList.
Below is the sample code.

```
List<Person> personList = getPersonList();
List<AddressMapping> addrMappingList = personToAddressMappingList();
```

Sample AddressMapping class:

```
class AddressMapping {

 private int id;
 private Person person;
 ..
}
```

Sample Person class:

```
Class Person{
  private int personId;
  private String personName;
  ...
 }
```

I want to iterate the `addrList` and for each `addrList` element i want to set the `personList` element.
Tried the below code:

```
for(AddressMapping addrMapping : addrMappingList){
  for(Person p : personList){
     addrMapping.setPerson(p);
  }
}
```

I should not iterate the Person inside the addrMapping as shown in the above code, any inputs would be helpful.
PS: Two list doesn't have any data to compare and set the value.

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: You should do clean coding.  Really catastrophe !

Comment: You want the n `Person` in `personList` to be set in the n `AddressMapping` of `addrMappingList`, right? Meaning that there should be one Person for each AddressMapping.

Comment: Can you please post your full implementation of AddressMapping and Person?

Comment: @JettoMartínez , Yes there should be one Person for each AddressMapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one iteration to do that. Since you actually need the index, it also means you can use a good old `for` loop for this:

```java
List<Person> personList = getPersonList();
List<AddressMapping> addrMappingList = personToAddressMappingList();

for(int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
    addrMappingList.get(i).setPerson(personList.get(i));
}
```

Of course, since `personList` and `addrMappingList` have the same number of elements, this is an option.

UPDATE

If by "with Java8" you mean using a more "modern" syntax, you could also use the following.

```java
List<Person> personList = getPersonList();
List<AddressMapping> addrMappingList = personToAddressMappingList();

IntStream.range(0, personList.size())
             .forEach(i -> addrMappingList.get(i).setPerson(personList.get(i)));
```

With all that, I think the first approach is better because this is a very simple function not worth overcomplicating. I don't really know if there is any performance benefits (And if there are, at what point they are noticeable), but unless it's significant I prefer readability (The KISS principle).

Comment: can we do the above using java8

Comment: @user222 Added a "modern" version, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the two lists are [*parallel arrays,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) and that the first element in one is paired with the first element of the other, etc., then you should not use an foreach-loop. Instead, manage the index explicitly:

```java
if (personList.size() != addrMappingList.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
for (int idx = 0; idx < addrMappingList.size(); ++idx) {
    addrMappingList.get(idx).setPerson(personList.get(idx));
}
```